# Avoiding and renaming .x and .y columns when merging or joining in r

Tags: r, dplyr

Often I go about joining two dataframes together that have the same name.  Is there a way to do this within the join-step so that I don't end up with a .x and a .y column?  So the names might be 'original_mpg', and 'new_mpg'?

```
  library(dplyr)
  left_join(mtcars, mtcars[,c("mpg",'cyl')], by=c("cyl"))
  names(mtcars) #ugh
```

Comment: rename them beforehand?... `names(df) <- paste("original", names(df), sep="_")`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Currently, this is an [open issue](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1296) with **dplyr**. You'll either have to `rename` before or after the join or use `merge` from base R, which takes a `suffixes` argument.

Comment: Nice, I wasn't aware of `suffixes`. Just to be nit-picky: OP actually wants `prefixes`, though...

Comment: Ok thank you both.  I didn't realize the suffixes/prefixes or that this sort of thing was actively being looked at.  I was just hoping I wouldn't have to rename AFTERWARDS as sometimes it can be confusing when this occurs to many columns or that you forget that a column changed.  And I don't always want to do it PRIOR since sometimes I don't actually want to change that name in the dataframe.  Thank you both though.

Comment: @runningbirds My comment was a little joke, prefixes does not exist as an argument of merge. Sorry, for being unclear!

Answer (score 23):

The default suffixes, `c(".x", ".y")`, can be overridden by passing them as a character vector of length 2:

```
library(dplyr)    
left_join(mtcars, mtcars[,c("mpg","cyl")], 
              by = c("cyl"), 
              suffix = c("_original", "_new")) %>% 
      head()
```

**Output**

```
 mpg_original cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb mpg_new
1           21   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4    21.0
2           21   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4    21.0
3           21   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4    21.4
4           21   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4    18.1
5           21   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4    19.2
6           21   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4    17.8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use suffix with a slightly modified function I found in the help of strsplit to make it a prefix

```
library(dplyr)    
mt_cars <- left_join(mtcars, mtcars[,c("mpg","cyl")], 
              by = c("cyl"), 
              suffix = c("_original", "_new"))
strReverse <- function(x){
   sapply(lapply(strsplit(x, "_"), rev), paste, collapse = "_")
}
colnames(mt_cars) <- strReverse(colnames(mt_cars))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had a similar question when I found this post.
I found a different solution to the question that I hope helps.

The solution is actually fairly simple, you generate a list with all the data frames you want to merge and use the reduce function.

```
library(dplyr)   

df_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)
df <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), df_list)
```

This was a solution to another problem I had, I wanted to simplify merging multiple dataframes. But if you use two dataframes in the list, it works all the same and merging does not rename the columns.

Comment: I like this out-of-the-box solution! Note that suffixes can be passed to dplyr's joins now